# How to add a font style for a specific letter only?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, calligraphy

In my latex document I of course have the normal lower case letter "k" in the default font. What I want to do is add the script version of this, "", to my document. I am not sure if I need to find a new font type so I can have `$\mathscr{k}$` return  (or some other math font command like mathpzc or mathcal), or if I need to find a package that will add the  as a separate character. In either case, I don't want to change anything else about my document. I only want to change `$\mathscr{k}$` to give  or add the character itself. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 4):

You can borrow the math script alphabet from STIX2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathscr}{LS1}{stix2scr}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{k}k$ and also $\mathscr{A}+\mathscr{V}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I could look to learn about the commands you used and their parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Several packages allow you to use `\mathscr{k}` in math mode.  I recommend using `unicode-math` in LuaLaTeX when you can, and legacy fonts when you have to.

Here is a MWE that sets up the Libertinus fonts through `fontsetup`, which loads `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertinus]{fontsetup}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{k}k$ and also $\mathscr{A}+\mathscr{V}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

Any OpenType math font will support lowercase script letters, although some might not use the style you prefer.  It is possible to substitute another font’s `\mathscr` alphabet with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  This MWE substitutes the alternative `\mathscr` alphabet of Stylistic Set 1 from STIX Two Math, which you will notice is less-heavily slanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertinus]{fontsetup}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range={scr,bfscr},
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  StylisticSet=1 ]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{k}k$ and also $\mathscr{A}+\mathscr{V}$

\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

In PDFLaTeX, you can select any script alphabet that supports lowercase letters with `mathalpha`, for example `\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{k}k$ and also $\mathscr{A}+\mathscr{V}$

\end{document}
```

[image: boondoxo font sample]

Comment: Thanks this is great! I think I can work with this, or at least I have something to work off of. I think the range= option is probably what I'm looking for.